# Python: Parsing JSON data from API get - referring to the dictionary key?

Tags: python, json, api, curl

I'm pretty new to Python so I'm only just starting to work with API's. I have retrieved the data I need from an API and it returns in the following format:

```
{u'id': u'000123', u'payload': u"{'account_title': u’sam b’, 'phone_num': ‘1234567890’, 'security_pin': u'000000', 'remote_word': u’secret123’, 'email_address': ‘email@gmail.com’, 'password': u’password123’}”}
```

So when I print my variable, it returns the above...

If I just want part of what it returns, how do I go about writing this? I was able to return id without issue, and if I specified 'payload' it returned everything after that. It seems like account_title, phone_num, security_pin, remote_word, email_address and password are all nested inside of 'payload'

Would would the best way be to have a variable, when printed, return just the email_address for example?

Thanks!

Comment: Your question is unclear. That JSON is already parsed as a Python dictionary. So it works just like any other dictionary. And the "payload" key itself contains another dictionary, which *also* just works like a normal dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to Python! Sounds like you're getting right into it. It would be best to begin reading fundamentals, specifically about the [Dictionary Data Structure](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries)

The Dictionary, or `dict` is what you are referencing in your question. It's a key-value store that is generally[1] un-ordered. The `dict` is a great way to represent JSON data.

Now you are asking how to extract information from a dictionary. Well, you seem to have it working out thus far! Let's use your example:

> d = {u'id': u'000123', u'payload': u"{'account_title': u’sam b’, 'phone_num': ‘1234567890’, 'security_pin': u'000000', 'remote_word': u’secret123’, 'email_address': ‘email@gmail.com’, 'password': u’password123’}"}

Now if we write `d['id']`, we'll get the `id` (which is 000123)

If we write `d['payload']`, we'll get the dictionary *within* this larger dictionary. Cool part about dicts, they can be nested like this! As many times as you need.

> d['payload']
>
> "{'account_title': u’sam b’, 'phone_num': ‘1234567890’, 'security_pin': u'000000', 'remote_word': u’secret123’, 'email_address': ‘email@gmail.com’, 'password': u’password123’}"

Then as per your question, if you wanted to get email, it's the same syntax and you're just nesting the accessor. Like so:

> d['payload']['email_address']

Hope that helps!

1. For the longest time, dicts were un-ordered in Python. In versions 3.6 and up, things began changing. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39980323/are-dictionaries-ordered-in-python-3-6) provides great detail on that. Otherwise, prior to that, using `collections.OrderedDict` was the only way to get a dict ordered by insertion-order

Comment: When I try the 2 square bracketed values next to each other like in your example, I get this error `TypeError: string indices must be integers` - any ideas?

Comment: @samrb Sounds like you're attempting to access a list like a dictionary. Are you sure you're using the same data as you presented in your question?